# How to break up an application cookie in to multiple cookies using Identity in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've noticed the cookie generated in my Core 2.0 app is very large. The cookie is associated with a domain, and some sites on the domain are running on Apache and NGINX which have limits of 8kb. For some users, the cookie can reach well over 8kb and throws an error when they try to access one of those sites.

Is there any way I can break up the cookie like so?:

1. First cookie holds basic user info (name, email, etc.). This is a
   very small amount of data and never reaches more than a few hundred
   bytes. This cookie will be shared across the domain for login
   purposes.
2. The second cookie would be the cookie that holds all of the user's
   role claims. This is the problem area because some users have a lot
   of claims. I want to associate this cookie with JUST the site, so it
   won't be shared across the domain.

Is there any way to do this with .NET Core 2.0 and Identity?

---

Here is the application cookie code in the `ConfigureServices` method of my `Startup` file:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".XAUTH";
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.DataProtectionProvider = protectionProvider;
    options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
    options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
 });
```

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Take a look at the [SessionStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.sessionstore) property.